# Countability of computable real numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, real-numbers, turing-machines

Is the set of all real numbers whose decimal expansions are computed by a machine not countable?

Assume a digital machine not capable of computing infinite decimal places.

Comment: Can your machine compute (or even store?) a decimal number with an infinite number of decimal places? Is it a digital or an analogue computer?

Comment: @KurtG. digital computer not capable of computing infinite decimal places

Comment: It is countable but probably not enumerable

Comment: Presumably there is an upper limit of the number of decimal places. Can the set of numbers you can write down in such a way be possibly *uncountable* ?

Comment: If it can only print finitely many digits, this is a subset of the rationals, and hence countable. But even with infinite digits allowed - say a non-halting Turing machine that produces a series of digits - there are only countably many, as well.

Answer (score 1):

For any programming language (Turing-complete or not) where programs consist of a finite (but unbounded) number of symbols taken from a finite alphabet, the number of possible programs is countable.

Any computable number can be defined by a program *P* that calculates the number accurate to within *n* decimal (or binary) places, where *n* is an integer provided by the user.  Since *P* and *n* are both part of countable sets, the possible outputs of $(P, n)$ pairs also forms a countable set.

Therefore, the number of computable numbers is countable.